# error when rendering through get_object_or_404 django

Tags: django

The following code in my `views.py` throws an error if I don't use 
`else` conditional statement specifying `detail = None`

Is there any better way to simplify the code without using `else` statement?
(just in case you don't understand the structure of my app, it only has detail, and list templates. `list.html` only shows the list of name record in model, and detail only shows the each name in detail page.)

```
def SimpleView(request, sluggy=None):
    s = Simple.objects.all()
    if sluggy:
        detail = get_object_or_404(Simple, slug=sluggy)
    else:
        detail=None
    return render(request,'simple_app/list.html',{'s':s,'d':detail})

def detaily(request,sluggy):
    sluggys = get_object_or_404(Simple,slug=sluggy)
    return render(request, 'simple_app/detail.html',{'sluggy':sluggys})
```

Comment: what error its throw

Answer (score 2):

You can build up the context directly:

```
def SimpleView(request, sluggy=None):
    context = {'s': Simple.objects.all()}
    if sluggy:
        context['d'] = get_object_or_404(Simple, slug=sluggy)
    return render(request,'simple_app/list.html', context)
```

(Though please use more descriptive names for the template vars; there's no reason to use single characters.)

Comment: This is better than my answer.

Comment: @Danie Roseman Thanks for your answer! I don't know how to interpret context['d'] since I have not set 'd' variable or key(is it in a dictionary format?)

Comment: `context` is just a dictionary, and `d` is just a key. It's being set at that point.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really fixated on no using the else part, you should define the detail variable before the if statement. So if "if qualification" is not satisfied, "detail" variable in return statement will at-least have a defined value as None.

```py
 def SimpleView(request, sluggy=None):
    s = Simple.objects.all()
    detail=None
    if sluggy:
        detail = get_object_or_404(Simple, slug=sluggy)
    return render(request,'simple_app/list.html',{'s':s,'d':detail})

def detaily(request,sluggy):
    sluggys = get_object_or_404(Simple,slug=sluggy)
    return render(request, 'simple_app/detail.html',{'sluggy':sluggys})
```